# Dual Booting Ubuntu and Windows 7 on a laptop without a Windows 7 DVD

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

I have a Samsung R480 and I want to install Ubuntu on it with Windows 7 on the side. The Windows 7 installer is in its own special partition in the hard disk. I read on the Ubuntu 10.10 documentation that I need a Windows 7 DVD. I wanna know why and if it really is necessary seeing as I don't plan on wiping my hard drive. I already have a big enough partition for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Windows is installed and you already have a separate partition for Ubuntu it should be possible to install it to this partition.

You can also try Ubuntu Installer for Windows: http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/windows-installer